# Why unhandled exception in a background thread doesnt crash the app domain?

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, exception, delegates

I am completely puzzled. I was so sure that .NET shuts the whole application domain if there is uncaught exception in a thread that I never tested this.

However I just tried the following code and it doesn't fail... Could anyone please explain why?

(Tried in .NET 4 and 3.5)

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Main thread {0}", Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);

    Action a = new Action(() =>
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Background thread {0}", Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);

        throw new ApplicationException("test exception");
    });

    a.BeginInvoke(null, null);

    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is happening because the `BeginInvoke` uses `ThreadPool` internally and when `ThreadPool` any unhadled exceptions will be silence fail. However if you use `a.EndInvoke` then the unhadled exception will be throw at the `EndInvoke` method.

Note: as `João Angelo` stated that using `ThreadPool` methods directly "like `ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItems` and `UnsafeQueueUserWorkItem`" will throw exceptions at 2.0 and above.

Comment: -1: Your answer also suggests that calling `ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem` with a method that throws an exception will result in the exception being eaten by the framework, which is not true in version 2.0 and after.

Comment: @João Angelo: The ThreadPool in general will not throw exceptions for example the new C# 4.0 Task will not throw exceptions but at the tast.Wait method just like the EndInvoke method.

Comment: again, that is a feature of the Task Parallel Library and not of the Thread Pool. Try using the thread pool directly and the exception will not be silenced.

Answer (score 6):

From [Exceptions in Managed Threads](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228965.aspx) on MSDN:

> In the .NET Framework version 2.0, the
> common language runtime allows most
> unhandled exceptions in threads to
> proceed naturally. In most cases this
> means that the unhandled exception
> causes the application to terminate.
>
> This is a significant change from the
> .NET Framework versions 1.0 and 1.1,
> which provide a backstop for many
> unhandled exceptions — for example,
> unhandled exceptions in thread pool
> threads. See Change from Previous
> Versions later in this topic.
>
> As a temporary compatibility measure,
> administrators can place a
> compatibility flag in the 
> section of the application
> configuration file. This causes the
> common language runtime to revert to
> the behavior of versions 1.0 and 1.1.
>
> ```
> <legacyUnhandledExceptionPolicy enabled="1"/>
> ```

Comment: Jon thank you for the effort but you failed to read the question.. The question is exactly WHY it DID NOT fail. Cheers

Comment: I understood the question, I'm telling you what the official guidance is on it, and giving you some possible reasons (framework version, config setting), and some further reading to understand what is going on :)

Comment: @Bobb: Is snappish criticism how you always respond to strangers who try to help you for free? How does that work out for you?

Answer (score 3):

Normally with asynchronous delegates if the delegated method throws an exception the thread is terminated and the exception will be thrown again in the calling code **only** when you call `EndInvoke`.

This is why when using an asynchronous delegate (`BeginInvoke`) you should always call `EndInvoke`. Also, this should not be confused with `Control.BeginInvoke` which can be called in a fire and forget manner.

Earlier I said normally, because there is a possibility for you to state that the exception should be ignored if the delegate method returns void. To do this you need to mark the method with the `OneWay` attribute.

If you run the following example, you will only get an exception when calling `willNotIgnoreThrow.EndInvoke`.

```
static void Throws()
{
    Console.WriteLine("Thread: {0}", Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);

    throw new ApplicationException("Test 1");
}

[OneWay]
static void ThrowsButIsIgnored()
{
    Console.WriteLine("Thread: {0}", Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);

    throw new ApplicationException("Test 2");
}

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Main: {0}", Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);

    var willIgnoreThrow = new Action(ThrowsButIsIgnored);
    var result1 = willIgnoreThrow.BeginInvoke(null, null);

    Console.ReadLine();
    willIgnoreThrow.EndInvoke(result1);

    Console.WriteLine("============================");

    var willNotIgnoreThrow = new Action(Throws);
    var result2 = willNotIgnoreThrow.BeginInvoke(null, null);

    Console.ReadLine();
    willNotIgnoreThrow.EndInvoke(result2);
}
```

Comment: @The Anonymous Downvoter, care to explain why do you think this does not answer the OP question?

Comment: Best I can work out Bobb is judging all questions as +1 or -1, and failing to understand what a downvote is for

Answer (score 0):

because exception throw on the given threads stays there unless it is channeled back to the main thread.

That's what backgroundWorker does it for you, if you have exception in the BackgroundWorker's thread, it gets rethrown on the main thread.

```
a.BeginInvoke(null, null);
```

this makes async call, which creates another thread to execute this

Comment: you are mixing up a 'background thread' and BackgroundWorker class.

Comment: not really, BackgroundWorker creates Background thread. The only difference between normal thread and back thread is that back thread doesnt hold up your appliaction from close down, while you have to wait for normal thread to finish its work.