# Why does an unhandled exception in this background thread not terminate my process?

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, asynchronous

I spawn a foreground thread and a background thread, throwing an exception in each.

```
using System;
using System.Threading;

namespace OriginalCallStackIsLostOnRethrow
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            try
            {
                A2();

                // Uncomment this to see how the unhandled
                // exception in the foreground thread causes
                // the program to terminate
                // An exception in this foreground thread
                // *does* terminate the program
                // var t = new Thread(() => {
                //     throw new DivideByZeroException();
                // });

                // t.Start();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                // I am not expecting anything from the
                // threads to come here, which is fine
                Console.WriteLine(ex);
            }
            finally
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Press any key to exit...");
                Console.ReadKey();
            }
        }

        static void A2() { B2(); }
        static void B2() { C2(); }
        static void C2() { D2(); }
        static void D2()
        {
            Action action = () => 
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"D2 called on worker #{Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId}. Exception will occur while running D2");
                throw new DivideByZeroException();
                Console.WriteLine("Do we get here? Obviously not!");
            };
            action.BeginInvoke(ar => Console.WriteLine($"D2 completed on worker thread #{Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId}"), null);
        }
    }
}
```

As expected, the unhandled exception in the foreground thread terminates the process. However, the unhandled exception in the background thread just terminates the thread and does not bring the process to a halt, effectively going unobserved and failing silently.

This program, therefore, produces the following output:

```
Press any key to exit...
D2 called on worker #6. Exception will occur while running D2
D2 completed on worker thread #6
```

This challenges my understanding about exception handling in threads. My understanding was that regardless of the nature of the thread, an unhandled exception, from v2.0 of the framework onwards, will bring the process to termination.

Here is a quote from [the documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h339syd0%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) on this topic:

> The foreground or background status of a thread does not affect the
>   outcome of an unhandled exception in the thread. In the .NET Framework
>   version 2.0, an unhandled exception in either foreground or background
>   threads results in termination of the application. See Exceptions in
>   Managed Threads.

Further more, the page titled [Exceptions in Managed Threads](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228965%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) states as follows:

> Starting with the .NET Framework version 2.0, the common language
>   runtime allows most unhandled exceptions in threads to proceed
>   naturally. In most cases this means that the unhandled exception
>   causes the application to terminate.
>
> This is a significant change from the .NET Framework versions 1.0 and
>   1.1, which provide a backstop for many unhandled exceptions — for example, unhandled exceptions in thread pool threads. See Change from
>   Previous Versions later in this topic.

**ANOTHER INTERESTING OBSERVATION**

Interestingly, if I cause the exception to be thrown in the *completion callback* instead of the actual action that is being done, the exception on the background thread in that case *does* cause a termination of the program. For code, please see below.

```
using System;
using System.Threading;

namespace OriginalCallStackIsLostOnRethrow
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            try
            {
                // A2();
                A3();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex);
            }
            finally
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Press any key to exit...");
                Console.ReadKey();
            }
        }

        static void A2() { B2(); }
        static void B2() { C2(); }
        static void C2() { D2(); }
        static void D2()
        {
            Action action = () => 
            {
                try
                {
                    Console.WriteLine($"D2 called on worker #{Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId}. Exception will occur while running D2");
                    throw new DivideByZeroException();
                    // Console.WriteLine("Do we get here? Obviously not!");
                }
                catch(Exception ex)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(ex);
                }
            };
            action.BeginInvoke(ar => Console.WriteLine($"D2 completed on worker thread #{Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId}"), null);
        }

        static void A3() { B3(); }
        static void B3() { C3(); }
        static void C3() { D3(); }
        static void D3()
        {
            Action action = () => { Console.WriteLine($"D2 called on worker #{Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId}."); };
            action.BeginInvoke(ar =>
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"D2 completed on worker thread #{Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId}. Oh, but wait! Exception!");

                // This one on the completion callback does terminate the program
                throw new DivideByZeroException();
            }, null);
        }
    }
}
```

**YET ANOTHER INTERESTING OBSERVATION**

Further, even more interestingly, if you handle the exception in the action that you want to execute using APM, in the `catch` block (set a breakpoint in the catch block in `D2()`), the `Exception` that appears has no stack trace other than the lambda being invoked. It has absolutely no information even about *how it got there*.

Whereas this is not true for exceptions that you trap in a catch block in *the completion callback*, as in the case of `D3()`.

I am using the C# 6.0 compiler in Visual Studio Community 2015 Edition and my program targets v4.5.2 of the .NET framework.

Comment: @ChrisO I did, but that's not the point here. The point is: the runtime termianted the thread and kept the process going, thus failing silently, which was not the behavior I was expecting. That I got a warning was only because I explicitly threw an exception. I could have not thrown that explicitly and called `Console.ReadLine()` for instance and divided some random number by the user input and still have received either a `FormatException` or a `DivideByZeroException`. That would not have changed the question through it would have gotten rid of the warning.

Comment: You're correct, the warning doesn't really matter to the context of the question.

Comment: I was surprised by this too. I saw this link which may shed some light: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6465517/why-unhandled-exception-in-a-background-thread-doesnt-crash-the-app-domain   The only time I saw anything similar was when a thread in a C# Windows service was calling `GetDirectories` and our lousy network lost its connection to the shared drive the thread was looking at. Rather than failing, the thread just stalled and the service continued without any warnings. Quite annoying as the thread was supposed to be doing something important.

Comment: You are supposed to call `EndInvoke` to propagate result/exception from asynchronous method call.

Comment: You experienced exactly the danger I am trying to highlight here with `D2()`.

Comment: @PetSerAl Thank you. That did it. Weird contraption, though. :-)

Comment: @PetSerAl I have posted your suggestion as an answer after trying it out. If you'd like to post an answer, I will mark yours as the right one.

Comment: Exposing a delegate's Begin/Invoke() methods was a C# v1 design mistake.  A necessary one, the only way in .NET 1.x to pass arbitrary arguments to a method that runs on another thread in a type-safe way.  They've been chipping away at it, anonymous methods in v2 was a good start, lambda expressions in v3 removed the need for them completely, async/await in v4.5 made it easy.  Just don't use them at all anymore.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As PetSerAl points out in the comments section of the question, to get the exception information, it is mandatory to call `EndInvoke` from inside the completion callback as shown below.

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.Remoting.Messaging;
using System.Threading;

namespace OriginalCallStackIsLostOnRethrow
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            try
            {
                A2();
                // A3();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex);
            }
            finally
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Press any key to exit...");
                Console.ReadKey();
            }
        }

        static void A2() { B2(); }
        static void B2() { C2(); }
        static void C2() { D2(); }
        static void D2()
        {
            Action action = () => 
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"D2 called on worker #{Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId}. Exception will occur while running D2");
                throw new DivideByZeroException();    
            };
            action.BeginInvoke(ar =>
            {
                ((Action)((ar as AsyncResult).AsyncDelegate)).EndInvoke(ar);

                Console.WriteLine($"D2 completed on worker thread #{Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId}");
            }, null);
        }

        static void A3() { B3(); }
        static void B3() { C3(); }
        static void C3() { D3(); }
        static void D3()
        {
            Action action = () => { Console.WriteLine($"D2 called on worker #{Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId}."); };
            action.BeginInvoke(ar =>
            {
                try
                {
                    Console.WriteLine($"D2 completed on worker thread #{Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId}. Oh, but wait! Exception!");
                    throw new DivideByZeroException();
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    throw ex;
                }
            }, null);

        }
    }
}
```

This is weird, and it still remains a mystery as to why the stack trace does not show up if you were to place a `try / catch` block in the action that is executing asynchronously.

I am referring to the absence of the *StackTrace*, not the absence of a call stack. :-)

[image]

Comment: The call stack is there. It's just that your delegate code is the first frame that you authored the code of. Make Visual Studio show external code.

Comment: @usr Of course, the call stack *has* to be there. I am referring to the absence of a stack trace. Please see picture in the updated answer. :-)

Comment: @usr I see the way I have named my namespace may have misled you to think that the last smaller of my questions in this question was about a *call stack*.